# unreasonable memory usage

Tags: centos, memory

I run a multi-process python program on CentOS. The program doesn't require a lot of memory. The wired thing is my 64GB memory machine is almost out of memory and have no ability to run other computationally intensive tasks. has anyone got the same problem? [image]

**Updated:**

after sort processes by %MEM with part of the output like that:

```
21922 haoyu     20   0 12.457g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.02 python
21871 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.02 python
21872 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.02 python
21895 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.02 python
21896 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.01 python
21897 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.03 python
21898 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.01 python
21899 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.02 python
21900 haoyu     20   0 12.433g 1.204g      0 T   0.0  1.9   0:00.01 python
```

the problem could be some mistakes in my multi-processes python program, looks the sub-processes hasn't been closed correctly and still take some memory. Since many of them are not currently active in using CPU, when applying top command without options I cannot see them.

Comment: Errr... so does top show anything else using memory? And if at all possible, please paste terminal output (instead of using an image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On attached by you image you have processes/programs sorted by CPU usage not MEMory usage.

Looks like python program you run uses ONLY 0.4% of memory (and 100% of CPU).
Probably another process/program is using memory on your server.

**Please run command which will generates list of programs sorted by memory usage:**

```
top -o %MEM -b -n 1 | head -20
```

and look at last column with name of process/program.

It should give you an answer for question, *What is using memory on your machine?*.